# Windows 2012 multiple users auto login

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, autologin

I have a windows 2012 server. And I have created a few users. Each user will run a batch script. Actaully the script will start a selenium node. I want those users can auto login when the server reboot.
Currently by editing the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
AutoAdminLogon  1
DefaultUserName myuser
DefaultPassword mypassword
ForceAutoLogon 1
```

One user can auto login, but that is not enough.
I am also trying to use mstsc (Remote Desktop) on powershell to login each users , but it is also difficult to do. 
I don't know if there have some way use powershell for user login.
And the reason why I need it is that I want selenium node to launch browser in the separate GUI environment to avoid IE mouse fouce issue。 
Anyone have a good idea on windows auto login ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't autologin several users this way. Add scheduled tasks to start all the needed scripts on system boot in "Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Task Scheduler".

Comment: I have try Task Scheduler before, but it didn't work. Although it can start the process (Run java -jar selenium-standalone). But the selenium node can't correctly launch IE and do testing. I don't know if it need some GUI env to launcher first. May be I figure out why it doesn't work

Comment: Do you know if the task scheduler can start IE or some programs with UI ?

Comment: Yes, it definitely can. You just need to check "Run only when user is logged on" in task properties, setup "At log on of any user" as a trigger and check also "Run task as soon as possible after the scheduled start is missed". The if you have AutoAdminLogon - the task will run on the system start.

Comment: Sorry, Anton, this way not work. I have User1 and User2. User1 is a auto log user, so with "Run only when user is logged on". But User2 can't. User2 have to manually login. And If I setup "Run with out user logon on". User2 will start the program after reboot. But without user logon, some of my test case will fail.

Comment: The key solve is still want both user User1 and User2 logon and start the program. I find there have a tool call "LogonExpert" which seems support Multi-user logon with command line.